# VBA Multiple Web Queries Hangs Even After Clearing Cache

Tags: excel, vba, excel-web-query

Couldn't find the solution anywhere. I'm download stock data for about 500 stocks using a Web Query. It will eventually hang before it downloads the entire stock list and I will have to the End Process. It works if I break the list into 3 separate parts. I've tinkered with the frequency of clearing the cache, but it hasn't solved the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub Download_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, STEnd As Long, STArray As Variant, TempSht As String, ST As String, SH As Worksheet
Dim symbols As String, sline As String, Values As Variant
Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
Dim ResearchSht As Worksheet: Set ResearchSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Research")
Dim Last As Long

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual

TempSht = "Template"

'Delete Old Sheets
For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
Select Case SH.Name
    Case ResearchSht.Name, "Template", "Trades"
    Case Else
        SH.Delete
End Select
Next

Last = ResearchSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
For j = 2 To Last
    ST = UCase(Trim(ResearchSht.Cells(j, 1)))
    ResearchSht.Cells(j, 1) = ST
    Worksheets.Add.Name = ST
    Select Case ST
        Case "^GSPC"
            SD = Day(Now)
            SM = Month(Now) - 1
            SY = Year(Now) - 10
            SY_2 = Year(Now)
        Case Else
            Check_Date
    End Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & ST & "&d=" & SM & "&e=" & SD & "&f=" & SY_2 & "&g=d&a=" & SM & "&b=" & SD & "&c=" & SY, Destination:=Sheets(ST).Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = ST
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1,2"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    'Split CSV data into columns
    STEnd = Sheets(ST).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To STEnd - 1
        STArray = Split(Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 1), ",")
        Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 1).Value = STArray(0)
        Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 2).Value = STArray(1)
        Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 3).Value = STArray(2)
        Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 4).Value = STArray(3)
        Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 5).Value = STArray(4)
        Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 6).Value = STArray(5)
        Sheets(ST).Cells(i, 7).Value = STArray(6)
    Next
    Sheets(TempSht).Range("H:AU").Copy Destination:=Sheets(ST).Range("H1")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Sheets(ST).Range("H:AL").Copy
    Sheets(ST).Range("H1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
    Sheets(ST).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden

  Select Case j
      Case 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700, 710, 720, 730, 740, 750, 760, 770, 780, 790, 800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 860, 870, 880, 890, 900, 910, 920, 930, 940, 950, 960, 970, 980, 990, 1000, 1010
          Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.Cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8"
  End Select
  'If ST <> "^GSPC" Then Sheets(ST).Delete 'Test
Next

ResearchSht.Activate
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: First I would seperate the WebService calls from all the Excel tinkering to isolate the problem. Are you able to call the WebService that often in a short timespan with other means (z.B. curl)?

Comment: I seperated the WebService from the rest of the code and it seems to have solved the issue. Thanks so much for your help. I'll let you know if I encounter any other issues as I re-write it. :)